# How can I tell which additional plugins are required to view a web page?

Tags: firefox

I am running a fresh Windows 7 64-bit installation with Firefox 6.

After navigating to http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx I get this message on top of the browser window:

> Additional plugins are required to display all the media on this page.

When I press "Install missing plugins" I get "No suitable plugins were found"

Is there any way to tell which additional plugins are required?

Comment: Additional information: tried this page in IE8. This plugin was Windows Genuine activation tool which seems to be ActiveX and obviously not recognized in Firefox. Got this plugin installed under IE, it verified validity of my Windows copy and I was able to proceed. Still would like to know how to find out the name of plugin in FF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could view the source code of the page, with (CTRL-U in Firefox)
Then press CTRL-F for search and type embed or object to search for possible plugin-calling code.

In the case of the page you posted, you will find the following code: 
type="application/mozilla-wat-scriptable-plugin-11"

You can then search for that, which will lead you to more information on the name of the plugin that is required.

Comment: I this case I would think that what is required on your system is Microsoft Silverlight but I haven't verified that as it goes beyond your original question.

Answer (score 1):

I am finding this on Google Mail, shockingly, and the object that appears to be causing the browser message is `ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")`. It surprises me that Google would depend on a MS technology, but it's the only required object visible in the source for the page that I can find so far. I'm using FF on a Mac (OS X Snow Leopard).